# How to jump to a Go struct definition in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, go

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download k8s source code : `git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.git`
2. Open it with Visual Studio

the Visual Studio Code version :Version: 1.66.2

The source code from `shared_informer.go`, delete comment ：

```golang
type SharedInformer interface {
    AddEventHandler(handler ResourceEventHandler)
    AddEventHandlerWithResyncPeriod(handler ResourceEventHandler, resyncPeriod time.Duration)
    GetStore() Store
    GetController() Controller
    Run(stopCh <-chan struct{})
    HasSynced() bool
    LastSyncResourceVersion() string
    SetWatchErrorHandler(handler WatchErrorHandler) error
    SetTransform(handler TransformFunc) error
}

type SharedIndexInformer interface {
    SharedInformer
    // AddIndexers add indexers to the informer before it starts.
    AddIndexers(indexers Indexers) error
    GetIndexer() Indexer
}
```

How to find `SharedInformer` is a member of `SharedIndexInformer`, if they are not in the same file; the method of the image is not working:

[image: the method]

Comment: That task is performed by the language server, do you have the Go plugin installed? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go

Comment: @aymericbeaumet  has installed